# Mix Voice to Video without losing video quality

Tags: video-editor, video-quality, audio, audio-recording, mixing

I have recorded video from Canon HFR 36 camera and recorded voice separately to computer using a clip on mic. (The video camera does not have mic input) Now I want a simple software to remove original audio from the video and add the recorded voice. When I make the edited file, the video quality should not be decreased dramatically.

I am using windows 8 Operating system. My video files are in MTS format (AVCHD). I recorded audio using windows voice recorder so that voice files are in wma format.

Comment: As you're in a hurry it's helpful to give as much information as possible such that people can help you fast and don't have to guess. What OS are you on? What is the format of the video file? What is the format of the audio file? How did you sync the audio and video recording?

Comment: sorry... I have edited the question.

Comment: You could use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9446578/1256347) a similar question is asked only with another video and audio format.

Comment: If you merge audio and video in Adobe Premiere, you can output in h.264 format and choose "match source".  The output file will (should?) be just as high quality as your original, according to what I've read online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tsMuxer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR) to simply switch out the audio in the MTS without re-encoding the video or audio. MTS is just a [container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_container), it's the "housing" for the video and audio streams. Though your audio has to have the exact same length to be in sync with the video and the audio format has to be supported by the [M(2)TS file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.m2ts).